# SSMS System out of memory

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

Every now and then, I'll get the following message on my screen when running something large in SSMS: `An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

The issue is, that once this error gets thrown, there seems to be no respite other than a reboot of the machine. I understand that this is an issue with memory on my machine and that this doesn't affect the server at all; however, rebooting in the middle of the day for a dev is never pleasant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you have to reboot? If you're running a 32bit version of SSMS, it's likely just using up 4GB of RAM. No reason to reboot at all. Just re-run the query or make it return a smaller data set or something

Comment: I'm using 64-bit. Once I get that message, it seems to be done. Even if I try to run `SELECT 1 + 1` in another window (with another connection) it'll still fail with the same error

Comment: Can you post the query you are executing when this happens? Is it consistent that it happens with just one query or multiple? Is it 1 table that causes this? Do you limit your batches? Have you optimized  your queries?

Comment: Closing SSMS should terminate the transaction and free up memory.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Doesn't happen with any particular query, though it does seem to happen while my machine experiences a spike in MEM usage. I'd assume that once that spike dies down, all would be ok; however, that unfortunately doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @WEI_DBA restarting SSMS seems to have done the trick. Thanks so much for your help! You should have put this as the answer.

Comment: For me this happened with 2014 when I had seriously been beating the crap of SSMS all day long. Connections to multiple servers and running massive queries all over the place. My first thought was a new tab, nope. So I closed the original tab but from there every single tab was the same thing. Odd for sure. I remember it clearly because it was just last week. :)

Comment: Odd. Every time this happens to me, I can just re-run the query and it might work fine after that. Unless I'm misremembering

Comment: Upgrade to 2017 or downgrade to 2014. SSMS 2016 has a bug where memory isn't freed, so after some point even the lightest query can result in OOM. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/confessions-of-a-microsoft-addict/2016/10/04/sql-2016-ssms-memory-leak/

Comment: So seriously you tried rebooting and not restarting SSMS in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I came up with the original "Comment" answer... Here it is.

Closing SSMS should terminate the transaction and free up memory.

Glad this worked out for you.

Comment: Is there any other way other than closing SSMS?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by closing some tabs, I have the bad habit of leaving them opened.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today when trying to get an execution plan for a troublesome query then SSMS became completely non responsive for me.

Was able to work around this by opening sqlcmd, finding the problem query with sp_who2 then killing it.

At this point I was able to access other tabs I had open in SSMS and copy a couple that had not been saved to a notepad. Of course, when I tried to do anything else Windows said that SSMS was not responsive and gave me the option to force close it or debug.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Deleting Temp file present on %temp% location. If the problem still happens restart SSMS.

This happened due to unused temp files.